# AngularJS ReferenceError: $window is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, redirect, window

I'm trying to re-direct my users if they pass my form validation (checking usernames and passwords against database values).

The validation works fine but in my .Success function the redirect doesn't seem to be working, it produces the error: 'ReferenceError: $window is not defined'.

Here's the code:

```
.success(function(data) {
    console.log(data);

        if (!data.success) {
            // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
            $scope.errorUserName = data.errors.userName;
            $scope.errorUserPassword = data.errors.userPassword;
        } else {
            // if successful, bind success message to message
            $scope.message = data.message;
            $window.location=('twitter.com');       
    }
});
```

I've tried changing the location path but nothing seems to be working. Any ideas?

Thanks!

LazyTotoro

Comment: Twitter.com is just a placeholder! :)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`$window` needs to be injected.

To inject it you simply add it as a parameter to your controller function and Angular will automatically take care of the rest.

For example:

```
app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $window) {

    $window.location = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
});
```

You can read more about dependency injection in AngularJS [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di).

If you don't need a full page reload you should instead inject and use [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location):

```
// get the current path
$location.path();

// change the path
$location.path('/newValue');
```

Comment: Thanks! I just tried "document.location.href=''" and it also worked! :D

Comment: Yeah, but inject that where?

Comment: not a complete answer for newbies... where is the inject, how to link the controller variable with a variable inside a controller's function?!

Comment: @Serge Notes taken and small edit made. Better now? Note however that this isn't supposed to be a guide on how dependency injection works, although the answer should of course be as helpful as possible.