# Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined

Tags: angular, webpack, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new in [Angular2](http://www.angular2.com/), I am trying to go through functionalities with a demo project and used prerendering with [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) in the code.

My code is here-

https://github.com/abrarjahin/Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App

I am getting this error-

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed because of error: ReferenceError: window is not defined
at D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:6541
at D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:6473
at e.exports (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:6759)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:3513)
at t (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:217)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:3381)
at t (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:217)
at Object.e.exports (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:2992)
at t (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:217)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:1615)
at t (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:217)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:779)
at t (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:217)
at Zone.current.fork.name (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:310)
at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:1:315)
Current directory is: D:\Dot.NetCore_Angular2_App\ProfileManagement
```

I never used any window in my code.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this error?

---

### Re-

I had checked this question - [AngularJS ReferenceError: $window is not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23392714/angularjs-referenceerror-window-is-not-defined)

But it is not helping.

---

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Can you include a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the question itself (rather than just linking to the entire project off-site)?

Comment: Sure, I will. But is there any common issue why I can get this error?

Comment: Please check the update for the question

Comment: My problem is similer like this- https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/220

Comment: did you find a solution to this? cause i am getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when import npm modules, I fixed this by replacing prerender attribute for app component at Index.cshtml page:

```
<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

to

```
<app asp-ng2-prerender-module="ClientApp/dist/main-server">Loading...</app>
```

Maybe it helps you.